# Woocommerce CSS align

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

On my wordpress, woocommerce website I am using an addon called Extra Product Option and what it does is self expanatory. Here is a link to a product page: 
https://www.fonster24.tk/produkt/tra-vridfonster/

The first to options with the title "Bredd" and "Höjd" are width and height. When you first go to the link, you can see that they are next to each other. However when you select another width the height dropdown jumps down below width. The reason is because the plugin/I am using conditional logic - so for every width option a "new" height appears (reason is because the pricing values of height are different depending on which width is selected). I have tried to add CSS `float: right/left` and `display: inline-block` on both of them and on height only.

The only time anything changes is when I set `float: right` (which is currently set for width and height when width 6 is selected).

Would really appreciate any help I can get :) Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are clearfix div added in your code after your select box so that just add css for clear that:

```
.tm-extra-product-options .cpfclear {
    float: none;
}
```

Comment: Welcome.... if it helps you please approve this as correct answer.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

add this below css

```
    .tm-extra-product-options .col-6, .tm-extra-product-options .tm-cell.col-6, .tc-cell.tc-col-6, .tc-col-6{width: 50%; float: left;}
.tm-extra-product-options .tm-extra-product-options-container, .tm-extra-product-options .tmcp-ul-wrap {
    float: left;
    overflow: visible;
}
.tm-extra-product-options .cpfclear {
    float: none;
    height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```